# stargazer() with Zelig regression output

Tags: r, latex, stargazer, r-zelig

I'm working with the R package `stargazer`.  I have a `Zelig` model that I can't get stargazer to create Latex code for.

```
logit9.1 <- zelig(winner ~ treatment + count_parties + resp_OECD24 + DirExp + IndExp,
    data = outcome, model = "logit" ,robust = TRUE)
stargazer(logit9.1)
Error in if (zelig.object$family$family == "gaussian") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

If I change model="normal", I get the same error message.  model="gaussian" is not a supported model in zelig().  The stargazer documentation says that it works with zelig objects.

Answer (score 3):

stargazer v. 2.0 is now available on CRAN. The package has been updated to reflect changes made to Zelig objects, and has a bunch of other new features. Zelig has not always been perfect about backward compatibility of the object it creates, so the old version of stargazer() might have trouble. Perhaps you should try running your code with the latest version, and see if it works.